# Make the bottom navigation disappear

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Default is in the bottom navigation state. The edit button is a button that appears when the edit mode is false, and the cancel button appears when the edit mode is true. When I press the edit button, the bottom navigation disappears and when I press the cancel or delete button, I need a code where the bottom navigation reappears. I tried to code it by myself, but it doesn't work well. Please help me :(
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYYbR.png)

Below shows some of my codes.

[fragment_like.xml]

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.~.like.LikeViewModel" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />
</data>
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_edit"
            style="@style/BodyMedium16"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="21dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_like_edit_btn"
            android:enabled="@{vm.selectedIds.size() >= 1}"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            android:text="@string/like_delete_btn"
            android:textColor="@color/gray050"
            android:visibility="@{vm.isEdit() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[activity_main.xml]

```
<data>

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.~.like.LikeViewModel" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bnv_main"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="104dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_white_fill_rect_topshadow"
            android:paddingHorizontal="18dp"
            android:paddingBottom="13dp"
            app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@style/Widget.~.BottomNavigationView.ActiveIndicator"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/sel_main_color_bnv_menu"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/CaptionBold10"
            app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/CaptionBold10"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/sel_main_color_bnv_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:visibility="@{vm.isEdit() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
```

[LikeFragment]

```
private fun initLikeEditBtnClickListener() {
        binding.btnLikeEdit.setOnSingleClickListener {
            mainViewModel.hideBottomNavigation()
        }
    }
private fun initEditBtnClickListener() {
        binding.btnEdit.setOnSingleClickListener {
            likeViewModel.activityList.observe(
                viewLifecycleOwner,
                Observer {
                    it?.let {
                        likeAdapter?.submitList(it)
                    }
                }
            )
            BindingToast.initLikeDeleteToast(
                requireContext(),
                getString(com.~.R.string.like_delete_complete)
            )?.show()
            mainViewModel.showBottomNavigation()
        }
    }
```

[LikeViewModel]

```
private val _isEdit = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
 val isEdit: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isEdit
init {
        _isEdit.value = false
    }
```

[MainActivity]

```
val likeViewModel by viewModels<LikeViewModel>()
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        binding.vm = likeViewModel
        initBnvItemSelectedListener()
    }
private fun initBnvItemSelectedListener() {
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fcv_main) ?: navigateTo<HomeFragment>()

        binding.bnvMain.setOnItemSelectedListener { menu ->
            when (menu.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_main_home -> navigateTo<HomeFragment>()
                R.id.menu_main_explore -> navigateTo<ExploreFragment>()
                R.id.menu_main_like -> navigateTo<LikeFragment>()
                R.id.menu_main_setting -> navigateTo<SettingFragment>()
            }
            true
        }
    }
```

[MainViewModel]

```
private val _isBnvVisible: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(true)
    val isBnvVisible: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isBnvVisible

    fun showBottomNavigation() {
        _isBnvVisible.value = true
    }

    fun hideBottomNavigation() {
        _isBnvVisible.value = false
    }
```